# MYSQL: Select Customers with the same state

Tags: mysql

Need to give a select statement which produces result:

```
State Name   customer1 customer2
```

I know i need to use `concat()` I'm just unsure how to identify customers with the same state

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select
state,
group_concat(customer_name) as customers
from table_name
group by state;
```

Note that for a large data you need to reset the value of `group_concat_max_len`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: Oh i was unaware of a group concat function, thankyou so much my friend